# Depend twice on the same build with different parameters

Tags: teamcity, build-dependencies

I currently have two TeamCity builds, `Foo` and `FooNuGet`.

`Foo` is a plain C++ compilation build: retrieve the source from VCS, compile it, gather the resulting `exe` and `dll` files as artifacts. It uses a configuration parameter (`%buildConfiguration%`) to choose whether to compile in Debug or Release mode.

`FooNuGet` has a snapshot + artifacts dependency on `Foo`. It runs CoApp on `Foo`'s artifacts to make a NuGet package out of them.

The issue is, I need to include both Release and Debug binaries inside that package. I had hoped to create two dependencies on `Foo` and configure them with both compilation modes, but it doesn't look like TeamCity offers this.

I see two other potential solutions:

- Create `Foo` as a template, then create `FooDebug` and `FooRelease` from this template. This is not ideal, as `Foo` itself is attached to a template already.
- <s>Create an additional `FooDebug` build that simply passes through artifacts from `Foo` (Debug), then Have `FooNuGet` depend on `Foo` (Release) and `FooDebug`. This would be a kludge, but looks the most promising to me.</s>

What should I do to end up with both versions of `Foo` at the beginning of `FooNuGet`?
Was it a mistake in the first place to make this configuration parameter?

---

#### Update

The second solution I anticipated turned out not to work at all. TeamCity apparently ignores parameters completely when picking a build to satisfy a snapshot dependency. The result was that `FooDebug`'s `%buildConfiguration%` was overriden (disregarded, really) and I ended up with two servings of Release artifacts in `FooNuGet`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just have 2 build steps for `Debug` and `Release` inside `Foo` build? And they would produce both `Debug` and `Release` binaries which you can pack in `FooNuGet` afterwards.

Comment: That's what was originally in place. The goal of the switch is to cut down on build times, since apart from `FooNuGet` everything uses only `Foo` (Release) most of the time.

Comment: Aha, I see. Then i'd agree that less confusing would be your 2nd option with separate builds for Debug and Release. Can't also think of any more appropriate solution for this setup than moving common parts to template and customizing changing parts with params.